# Autenticación interna de oauth 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, oauth2

Quiero realizar una aplicación embebida.
Este es el código que genera el token:

```
private static string authority = "https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize";

static string AccessToken()
{
    if (token == String.Empty)
    {
        TokenCache TC = new TokenCache();

        authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority, TC);

        token = authContext.AcquireToken(resourceUri, clientID, new Uri(redirectUri), PromptBehavior.RefreshSession).AccessToken;
    }
    else
    {

        token = authContext.AcquireTokenSilent(resourceUri, clientID).AccessToken;
    }

    return token;
}
```

Pero no quiero que el oauth 2.0 me genere una ventana de autenticación pidiéndome los datos, sino, pasar los datos de autenticación como parámetros para que me genere el token por interno para que el usuario no tenga que loguearse y pueda ver los datos de una cuenta maestra.

Comment: Podrias editar tu pregunta y añadirle el codigo

Comment: Lee **[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** con el código que hayas intentado, errores, etc. Puedes consultar aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Saludos.